# Summernote is not inserting html in code view without adding extra tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I have tried to insert html code in summernote codeview. But it is not working as expected. The code view is creating a separate html tag when inserting the text in between. Please check the example code below:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.summernote').summernote({
    airMode: false,
    tabDisable: true,
    popover: {
      air: [
        [
          'font',
          [
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'underline',
            'strikethrough',
            'superscript',
            'subscript',
            'clear',
          ],
        ],
      ],
    },
    height: '200 px',
    width: '90%',
    toolbar: [
      ['misc', [ 'codeview']],
      [
        'font',
        [
          'bold',
          'italic',
          'underline',
          'strikethrough',
        ],
      ],
      ['para', ['paragraph']],
      ['custom',['textManipulator', 'shortCode']],
    ],

  });

});

(function (factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['jquery'],factory);
  } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));
  } else {
    factory(window.jQuery);
  }
}(function ($) {
  $.extend(true, $.summernote.lang, {
    'en-US': {
      shortCode: {
        tooltip: 'Short Codes',
        currency: '$',
      }
    }
  });
  $.extend($.summernote.options, {
    shortCode: {
      icon: '<i class="note-icon"><svg width="14" height="14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><g><text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0)" stroke="null" font-weight="bold" xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="Noto Sans JP" font-size="10" id="svg_6" y="10.46872" x="-0.03119" fill="#000000">&lt; &gt;</text></g></svg></i><span class="note-icon-caret"></span> ',
      // noteSatus: 'position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0',
      menu: [
        'NAME',
        'FIRST_NAME',
        'LAST_NAME',
        'EVENT',
        'DATE',
        'TIME',
        'LINK',
        'SHORT_LINK',
        'REPLAY',
        'REPLAY_SHORT',
        'LIVE',
        'COUNTDOWN'
      ]
    }
  });
  $.extend($.summernote.plugins, {
    'shortCode': function(context) {
      var ui        = $.summernote.ui,
          $note     = context.layoutInfo.note,
          options   = context.options,
          lang      = options.langInfo;
      context.memo('button.shortCode', function () {
        var button = ui.buttonGroup([
          ui.button({
            className: 'dropdown-toggle',
            contents: options.shortCode.icon,
            tooltip: lang.shortCode.tooltip,
            container: 'body',
            data: {
              toggle: 'dropdown'
            }
          }),
          ui.dropdown({
            className: 'dropdown-template',
            items: options.shortCode.menu,
            click: function (e) {
              var $button = $(e.target);
              var menuSelect = $button.data('value');
              e.preventDefault();
              var selection = $note.summernote('createRange').toString();
              if ($('.summernote-textManipulatorAlert').length > 0)$('.summernote-textManipulatorAlert').remove();
                var modded = "";
                switch (menuSelect){
                  case 'ATTENDEE':
                    modded = '#ATTENDEE#';
                    break;
                  case 'FIRST_NAME':
                    modded = '#FIRST_NAME#';
                    break;
                  case 'LAST_NAME':
                    modded = '#LAST_NAME#';
                    break;
                  case 'EVENT':
                    modded = '#EVENT#';
                    break;
                  case 'PRESENTER':
                    modded = '#PRESENTER#';
                    break;
                  case 'DATE':
                    modded = '#DATE#';
                    break;
                  case 'TIME':
                    modded = '#TIME#';
                    break;
                  case 'LINK':
                    modded = '#LINK#';
                    break;
                  case 'SHORT_LINK':
                    modded = '#SHORT_LINK#';
                    break;
                  case 'REPLAY':
                    modded = '#REPLAY#';
                    break;
                  case 'REPLAY_SHORT':
                    modded = '#REPLAY_SHORT#';
                    break;
                  case 'LIVE':
                    modded = '#LIVE#';
                    break;
                  case 'COUNTDOWN':
                    modded = '#COUNTDOWN#';
                    break;
                }
                if(modded != 'textManipulatorError') $note.summernote('insertText', modded);
              /* } */
            }
          })
        ]);
        return button.render();
      });
    }
  });
}));

function toWords (i) {
  var r = /[A-Z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xDE]?[a-z\xDF-\xF6\xF8-\xFF]+|[A-Z\xC0-\xD6\xD8-\xDE]+(?![a-z\xDF-\xF6\xF8-\xFF])|\d+/g;
  return i.match(r);
}

function toCamelCase (iA) {
  var r = "";
  for(let i = 0 , l = iA.length; i < l; i++) {
    var cS = iA[i];
    var tS = cS.toLowerCase();
    if(i != 0) tS = tS.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + tS.substr(1);
    r += tS;
  }
  return r;
}

var htmlString = `<div class="section-box ew-no-shadow no-padding" style="font-family: Roboto,sans-serif; margin: 0;border-radius: 18px;box-shadow: none!important; background-color: #fff;overflow: hidden;position: relative; padding: 0"> <div class="full-widget-form"> <div class="form-widget-body" style="padding: 2.2rem 4rem; text-align: center;"> <h3 style="font-size: 26px;font-weight: 700!important;margin: 10px 0; word-break: break-word;">#NAME#</h3> <p style="color: #666; margin: 0 0 12px; font: 400 14px/22px Roboto, sans-serif;">#DATE##TIME#</p><span class="notif-message-preview" style="background: #f6f8f9;font-size: 16px;min-height: 154px;display: block; padding: 20px;text-align: left; line-height: 27px;margin: 25px 0 10px;">Hi #NAME#,<br><br>Thank you for registering for our webinar. You'll be able to connect using the button below. When the webinar begins, we'll send the link as a reminder.</span> <div class="widget-action-registration" style="padding: 0;"> <button mat-flat-button="" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-flat-button mat-button-base mat-accent" style="background-color: #000; min-width: 126px; width: auto; padding: 14px 2rem; margin: 0!important;line-height: normal; font-size: 15px;height: auto; font-weight: 500; box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%), 0 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0 0 0 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%); min-height: 40px;color: #fff; border-radius: 8px; text-transform: none; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif; border: none; white-space: nowrap; text-align: center; outline: none; cursor: pointer;"><span class="mat-button-wrapper" style="white-space: break-spaces;">Join Event</span> <span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span> </button> </div><span class="join-link-notf" style="display: block;font-size: 16px;font-weight: 700;margin-bottom: 15px;margin-top: 30px;">Your joining link:</span> <a href="#SHORT_LINK#" class="" style="font-size: 16px;color: #27ae60;">#SHORT_LINK#</a> </div></div></div>`;

$('.summernote').summernote('pasteHTML', htmlString);
```

Please check the jsfiddler implementation:
https://jsfiddle.net/munishg/2fdakgho/2/

In this when the user even presses enter in the editor, it is creating a closing and opening span tag. I want to eliminate this behavior.
As in this you can see that my custom component is inserting text on click. But a separate span tag is being created automatically if it try to insert in between text.